# Include Angular Index (Main page) in php page

Tags: php, angular

I am developing a web api (service) project using php. Now I want to add an Angular client to it but under the same project directory. So I have added that with command `ng new my-php-app-name` and generated it in the same directory of my php app. As I have figured out, each time I want to get results from angular I should run it by `npm start` (to keep compiling) or `ng build` to build it one time. So now when I use `npm start` the app starts in the port 4200 and works fine.

How can I include the main page of that angular application in my php pages. I have tested including "src/index.html" but it didn't work.

It is worth mentioning that the angular project is created using [this tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart).

The project tree is like bellow:

```
.
├── ~
├── client_app
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── composer.phar
├── config
│   └── cli-config.php
├── controllers
│   ├── account_controller.php
│   ├── home_controller.php
│   └── unitapi_controller.php
├── e2e
│   ├── app.e2e-spec.ts
│   ├── app.po.ts
│   └── tsconfig.e2e.json
├── helpers
│   ├── HASHHELPER.php
│   ├── rb.php
│   ├── STRINGHELPER.php
│   └── URLHELPER.php
├── index.php
├── karma.conf.js
├── models
│   ├── bootstrap.php
│   ├── entities
│   │   ├── additional_field.php
│   │   ├── additional_value.php
│   │   ├── good_request.php
│   │   ├── unit.php
│   │   └── user.php
│   └── viewmodels
│       └── unit_list_viewmodel.php
├── node_modules
│   ├── ...
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── protractor.conf.js
├── README.md
├── routes.php
├── services
│   ├── account_service.php
│   └── unit_service.php
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.component.css
│   │   ├── app.component.html
│   │   ├── app.component.spec.ts
│   │   ├── app.component.ts
│   │   └── app.module.ts
│   ├── assets
│   ├── environments
│   │   ├── environment.prod.ts
│   │   └── environment.ts
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── polyfills.ts
│   ├── styles.css
│   ├── test.ts
│   ├── tsconfig.app.json
│   ├── tsconfig.spec.json
│   └── typings.d.ts
├── tests
│   ├── add_user.php
│   ├── entity_manager_type.php
│   ├── get_user.php
│   └── sample_query.php
├── tree.txt
├── tsconfig.json
├── tslint.json
├── UsefulCommands.txt
├── vendor
│   ├── ...
└── views
    ├── account
    │   └── login.php
    ├── home
    │   └── index.php
    ├── layout.php
    └── shared
        └── error.php

3511 directories, 22335 files
```

Comment: I have solved this. IGW I will publish it on github for everyone use.